# Renaming files in linux with a regex

Tags: linux, regex, rename

I had a group of files that I'd like to consistently rename, the files are named things like

```
"System-Log-01-01-2009-NODATA.txt"
"Something-Log-01-01-2009-NODATA.txt"
```

And I wanted them as lowercase, yyyymmdd, .log extension

```
"system.20090101.log"
"something.20090101.log"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I used to write perl scripts to do this, until I discovered the rename command.

It accepts a perl regex to do the rename:

for this, I just typed two commands:

```
rename 's/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\d\d)-(\d{4})-NODATA.txt\$1.$4$3$2.log$//' *
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *.log
```

For some distros though, `rename` doesn't have this functionality (see its man page), and you may have to install `perl-rename` or `prename`.

Comment: very nice answer

Comment: Beware, some distros ship a worthless rename command. Check which one your distro has first.

Comment: I knew `mmv` but eventually thanks to `rename` I can use the power of regex

Comment: On Arch Linux this is `perl-rename`.

Answer (score 7):

[mmv](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/mmv.html) is a standard linux utility to move/rename multiple files. It is available from the repos for most distributions. For your example above, you could do:

```
mmv '*-Log-*-*-*-NODATA.txt' '#l1.#4#3#2.log'
```

For more information, read this [debaday article](http://debaday.debian.net/2007/06/13/mmv-mass-moving-and-renaming-files/) or the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/mmv.1.html).

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks. I had to add single quotes otherwise mmv wound do nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Since i don't have a rename command, i am relying on this:

```
for myfile in /my/folder/*; do
    target=$(echo $myfile|sed -e 's/foo/bar/g')
    mv "$myfile" "$target"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

`rename` util is not very "standard". Each distro ships with a different `rename` tool. For instance, here on Gentoo, `rename` is from `sys-apps/util-linux` package and does not support regex.

*Hamish Downer* suggested `mmv`, it seems useful, specially for use inside scripts.

On the other hand, for the general case, you might want [renameutils](http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/). It has `qmv` and `qcp` commands, which will open a text editor of your choice (my preference: Vim) and allow you to edit the destination filenames there. After saving and closing the editor, `qmv`/`qcp` will do all the renaming.

Both `mmv` and `qmv` are smart enough to rename files in correct order and also to detect circular renames, and will automatically make a temporary file if needed.

Comment: On Gentoo you can also emerge the `sys-apps/rename` package, which gives you `renamexm` which will do regex renaming as well as mass upper/lowercase and other nice things.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair:

```
rename 's/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\d\d)-(\d{4})-NODATA.txt\$1.$4$3$2.log$//' *.txt
```

gives this output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $4 in regexp compilation at (eval 1) line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $3 in regexp compilation at (eval 1) line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $2 in regexp compilation at (eval 1) line 1.
```

But:

`rename -n 's/(\w+)-\w+-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})-NODATA\.txt$/$1.$4$3$2\.log/' *.txt && rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' System.20090101.log`

gives the right output:

```
System-Log-01-01-2009-NODATA.txt renamed as System.20090101.log
System.20090101.log renamed as system.20090101.log
```

replacing {-n} switch with {-v}

Answer (score 1):

I created a small bash script to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in `ls /path/to/folder`; do
  # Create new filename from the old one
  # This example replaces A (upper case) with a (lower case)
  new_file=`echo "$new_file" | tr A a`

  # Rename the file
  mv "$f" "$new_file"
done
```

Comment: In general parsing `ls` output is not the best idea. A random search pulled up this longish read on [Unix . SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) for your amusement. | In addition your answer would better match the question with a `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon a python command-line tool called regex-rename, to install it, just run:

```
pip3 install --user regex-rename
```

To test your regex:

```
regex-rename '(\w+)-(\w+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-NODATA(\.txt)'
```

The actual renaming would be:

```
regex-rename '(\w+)-(\w+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-NODATA(\.txt)' '\1.\5\4\3\6' --rename
```